# Vue.js - Unable to access values in object in template

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

I am having trouble accessing a basic object in my Vue template.

This code:

```
{{event.portalData["Group Schedule"]}}
```

Shows this in the template

```
[ { "recordId": "5555666", "Group Schedule::_kp_group_schedule_id": "GRSCH1111", "Group Schedule::group number_display": "A",} ]
```

I cannot get access to the values. Have tried

```
{{event.portalData["Group Schedule"]["Group Schedule::group number_display"]}}
```

and

```
{{event.portalData["Group Schedule"][0]["Group Schedule::group number_display"]}}
```

Usually one of these works, but neither fix it. I also checked that it is in fact an object using `typeof()` and it confirmed as an Object.

If anyone can tell me what is going wrong here and how I can fix it I'd much appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: `[ { "recordId": "5555666", "Group Schedule::_kp_group_schedule_id": "GRSCH1111", "Group Schedule::group number_display": "A",} ][0]["Group Schedule::group number_display"]` is working great in a basic console.
So here, it's more of an async issue ? Or maybe just syntax.  
Can you provide a link to try it somewhere (like codesandbox) ?